# Spatial table spanning

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to create a table like this: 2 row and 2 columns are "spanned", to create 3 merged cells.

How do I do this?

[image: table example]

Comment: Are you using a table here to present tabular data, or are you using it for layout? Normally a `float:right` would be a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic idea to do this. You can `colspan` property to do this.

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:green"></td>
        <td style="background-color:Red"></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:green" colspan="2"></td></tr>
</table>
```